# Como manipular a posição de uma div

Tags: javascript

Preciso manipular a posição de duas `<div>` em movimentos opostos.

Pesquisei em muitos lugares porém não achei nenhuma explicação de como tal efeito pode ser feito e nem meios de como fazê-lo.

Não queria pedir a resposta, mas não sei sequer como pesquisar a respeito!

Comment: Explica melhor o que você está querendo fazer! Você está querendo animar as divs em direções opostas?

Comment: var i=-1;
var u=1;
  function mover(op){
                if(op=='esquerda'){
document.getElementById("div03").style.left=i+"px";
                        i--;
                }
                if(op=='direita'){
document.getElementById("div03").style.left=i+"px";
                        i++;
                }
                if(op=='baixo'){document.getElementById("div03").style.top=u+"px";
                        u++;
                }
                if(op=='cima'){
document.getElementById("div03").style.top=u+"px";
                        u--;
                }
        }

Answer (score 5):

Não vou dar a resposta de como movimentar duas divs em sentidos opostos, mas aqui vai o básico sobre como manipular um elemento HTML.

Considere esta div:

```
<div id="minhaDiv"></div>
```

No JavaScript, você precisa:

```
// 1. Acesso ao objeto do DOM que representa a div
var div = document.getElementById('minhaDiv');

// 2. Manipular o objeto *style* da div para alterar sua aparência (incluindo posição)

// 2.1 Aparência
div.style.width = '50px';
div.style.height = '50px';
div.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';

// 2.2 Posição
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top = '100px';
div.style.left = '50px';

// 3. Pegadinha! Atenção ao alterar a posição baseada na atual:
var leftAtual = parseInt(div.style.left, 10);
div.style.left = (leftAtual + 5) + 'px'; // desloca 5px para a direita
```

Para animar a posição, você vai precisar lidar com uma destas 3 funções:

- [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)
- [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)
- [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Comment: +1. Complementando a "pegadinha": lembrar também de usar a unidade certa (se estava em `px`, setar como `px`, se estava em `em` setar como `em` etc). Ou fazer a conversão de uma pra outra. (P.S. Ou eu estou enganado, e no valor do estilo se está sempre em `px`?)

Comment: Ok. acho que entendi! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Foi de grande Avalia!

Comment: @mgibsonbr Boa pergunta, vou testar mais tarde. Mas acho que a unidade varia mesmo.

Comment: Pelo jeito [ele converte...](http://jsfiddle.net/9oxr2sc1/) É por isso que eu gosto de jQuery, com JS puro uma coisinha simples dá um trabalho danado, e fica cheio de *edge cases*: por exemplo, se o estilo anterior for computado, ler o valor `style` não trará nenhum resultado. Aff

Comment: No caso usando Jquery é mais simples?

Comment: [A unidade varia sim](http://jsfiddle.net/9oxr2sc1/1/) (fiz o exemplo anterior com pressa, agora que voltei percebi o erro...). @JoãoPedro a questão é que se inicialmente seu elemento foi posicionado usando uma folha de estilo, o atributo `style` estará vazio (como o exemplo acima demonstrou), é necessário usar `getComputedStyle` para obter o valor correto. Com jQuery, é simplesmente `.css(atr)` pra ler e `.css(atr, valor)` pra escrever, e a conversão pra número e pra `px` é feita automaticamente ([exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/9oxr2sc1/2/)).